# windows 8 and 0x84 partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I have a Samsung serie9 (ultrabook NP900X4C-A01IT). I have just one 256GB SSD divided in 4 primary partitions. The  OS is Windows 8. No UEFI bios enabled and no GPT partitioning.

I wish to install Ubuntu 12.10 in dual boot with windows 8 and I need a free primary partition (eventually to transform in extended partition for Ubuntu)

The partitions now are:

1. 100 MB active, boot,system partition , NTFS ,0x27 (windows 8)
2. 200 GB active, system partition , NTFS, 0x27(windows 8)
3. 0x84 partition , not formatted (all zeroes on the surface) , OEM? Hibernate?.I don't know....What is it?
4. 30 GB PQ_SERVICE partition , 0x27.

I wish to delete the 3) partition...the 0x84...and to shrink the others.

What is that 0x84 partition? Is it a OEM partition?
And what is an OEM partition?

Is it an Hibernate partition?
I' dont believe because I have my "hiberfil.sys" file in c:\ as it should be.

Do I need it?

P.S.= I can't use GPT partitioning according to some linux distributions, and I wish not.

Answer (score 1):

> What is that 0x84 partition?

According to Wikipedia's [list of partition types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type) type 0x84 is used to mark a partition used for:

- IBM OS2 hidden filesystem (obviously not in your case), or
- Hibernation (Not needed since windows can (and should) use your hiberfil.sys
- A windows 7 [rapid start technology](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-033637.htm) partition.

> What is an OEM partition?

An OEM partition is the name usually assigned to a partition which your OEM (in your case Samsung) buts on your harddisk for whatever goal or extra they want it for. Sometimes it contains the files needed to restore a laptop to factory defaults (reformat whole disk, restore OS and bloatware). Sometimes it contains actually useful features.

Most people I know seem to make a full system backup (just in case), and then delete this usually unneeded partition. (Along with a clean install of the OS without bloatware).

> Do I need it?

Almost certainly not.  **Almost**.  Make a full disk backup before you delete it.

> P.S.= I can't use GPT partitioning according to some Linux distributions, and I wish not.

I am not sure I understand this correctly. It seems to contain two parts:

1. I can not use it according to some distribution.
2. I do not wish to use it.

For 1, well use a modern distribution. GPT is not precisely new and everything from the last 6 years or so should support it.

For 2: Your choice. If you do not wish to use it, then do not use it. :)

Comment: Wow!Thank you for your fast answer..I have already made a full system backup. So in my case the 0x84 partition seems to be for the rapid start technology since the others options are "false"..don't you think so? Otherwise it has all zeros on the surface and all the partitioning programs say it is "not formatted".I will delete it...About the last two points,you're right ,it's my choice,but maybe I didn't understand very well. What have I to do for enabling GPT?In the BIOS I have the option to enable UEFI;is it that?Is it possible to enable GPT without UEFI? How can I see if I have GPT?Thanks

Comment: GPT is a different way of partitioning a disk. It replaced the old style MBR and has a few advantages such as no primary(4) or secondary partitions but simply a list of over 100 partitions. It also supports drives larger than 2TB. Downside is that windows XP does not understand it, and that some older motherboards fail to boot from GTP or do so in a flawed way. I guess that is just the way of relative new things. -- It is possible to convert MBR disks to GPT formatted disks, but this will probably not work if you are actively using an OS on the disk (read: you will need to boot from USB orCD).

Comment: It is also quite possible that changing the disk format will break the current windows 8 format. And with a 256MB drive you do not need GTP. YOu only really need it for drives greater than 2TB.